# how to resolve the 403 error (We're sorry, but your computer or network may be sending automated requests)?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am currently working on a laravel 8 project, and I am using the google drive api on this project, but sometimes when I send requests to the google drive api I get the 403 error (We are sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated requests.) how to fix or how to disable this security on google drive account ?

for my project to communicate with my google drive account I installed in my project "google/apiclient": "~2.11", then I added

- App\Providers\GoogleDriveServiceProvider::class has my app.php
- create a Providers file that I named GoogleDrvieServiceProviders in which I wrote the following code:

```or-tag-here
{

  Storage::extend('google', function($app, $config) {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
  $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
  $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
  $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $adapter = new GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $config['folderId']);
       

  return new Filesystem($adapter);
});
```

```
- and in my .env I added the following authentication information
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=2032442....
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=GOCSPX......
GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN="1//04z...."
GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID=1eiNw.....


NB:the project communicates correctly with the google drive account, but sometimes for several minutes I receive the 403 error (We are sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated requests.)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] we need to see your code.

Comment: @DaImTo I added my code

Comment: There isnt enough code here to diagnose the issue.   I need a [example] if your looping somewhere wheres the loop where are you sending the requests.

Comment: @DaImTo: hi, here are the steps that I followed to synchronize my project with the api above, now when I save a file on the drive, I store the link of this file in the database, and it is this link that I use to access the file, there is no loop

Comment: What link to the file the one from drive?  You know that thats not static right? and only someone with access to the file is going to be able to open it.

Comment: To be clear in need to see the code that is causing "We are sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated requests."  what is GoogleDriveAdapter what is Filesystem I need a [example] that causes the error that i can test

Comment: @DaImTo :the file download link it is on the form (https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FileId.....&export=media)

Comment: @DaImTo: to better explain googledriveadapter the best is to share with you the github link which allowed me to use the google drive api on the project

the link:  https://gist.github.com/sergomet/f234cc7a8351352170eb547cccd65011